# Difference between ontology and wordnet

Tags: nlp, ontology, wordnet

what is the difference between the word net and the ontology? As far as I know wordnet can be extended to ontology. If so how can we do that?

Comment: I don't understand why you would put a bounty on this question. It appears that the misunderstanding was a terminological issue. There is nothing else to say.

Comment: I do not put a bounty on this

Comment: I know, @alvas did. I thought my comment would be attached to the bounty announcement.

Comment: lol, i think this is a worthy question to consider deeply. actually the wordnet ontology is based on SUMO which has been upgraded to YAGO and YAGO2. but it isn't merged back to wordnet.

Comment: @alvas I think you over-interpreted the question. It asks about "the difference between the word net and the ontology". It's not meant to discuss the relationship between Wordnet and SUMO (and its avatars)

Comment: @alvas Maybe you should discuss the content of the question with Chamath Sajeewa, and suggest some edits. However, and once again, I don't think you are talking about the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ontologies. Wordnet is one of them.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a serious SO answer. I agree with alvas' comments. I'd say wordnet is a database more than it's an ontology or try to explain what sort of linguistic resource it is. You can note that anything that could be (or is already) parsed to triples can be interpreted as an ontology or KB, and so on. Your answer just says "wordnet is an ontology", I don't think this is sufficient.

Comment: btw, here's some more discussion: http://mailman.uib.no/public/corpora/2014-August/020939.html

Comment: @alvas nice one. maybe it would be a good thing to have a synthesis of the discussion as an answer... and perhaps you should edit the question too.